# Finding elements with .next() regardless of nesting

Tags: jquery

Assuming this sort of structure:

```
<li class="page-title">Global</li>
<ul>
    <li class="element">Design Elements</li>
    <li class="page-title">Alerts</li>
    <ul>
        <li class="element">Alert 1</li>
        <li class="element active">Alert 2</li>
        <li class="element">Alert 3</li>
        <li class="element">Alert 4</li>
        <li class="element">Alert 5</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
<li class="page-title">Accounts</li>
<ul>
    <li class="element">Accounts Main</li>
</ul>
```

How can I step through the `.element` elements regardless of the nesting structure?

Currently, I'm using `.next('.element')`, but at the top or bottom of the set of elements, it starts to return nulls.

I'd like to avoid using some sort of "if this is the last in the set, set up a level and get back in" logic if possible.

EDIT: I should clarify, I'm looking to step up and down a list of these having bound the up and down keys, so I need to be able to select the actual relative next element for whatever's got `.active`.

So, assuming we're on Alert 2, a function I've left out runs based on a data-job attribute. We hit the up key, it steps to Alert 1, runs that function again. I'd like to be able to hit the up key again, and it pops up to 'Design Elements'.

Comment: You can also use `find()` on the body or document.
Also it's worth look at the `children()` selector method. http://api.jquery.com/children/

Comment: There is no selector or method that does this, therefore you will have to select all, then get the index of the current in all and select the next one via index.

Comment: Alright, sounds like I'll have to get my hands dirty then. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out on my own!

I'm including the bit for watching the up and down keys as well.

```
$(window).keyup(function(e){

    if (e.keyCode == 40){
        var next_element = $('.active').next('li.element');

        if($('.active').is('li:last-of-type' || 'li:only-of-type')){

            next_element = $('.active').parent().nextAll().eq(1).children('.element:first-of-type');
        }   
            elementExpand(next_element);
                }

    if (e.keyCode == 38){
        var prev_element = $('.active').prev('li.element');

        if($('.active').is('li:first-of-type' || 'li:only-of-type')){
            prev_element = $('.active').parent().prevAll().eq(1).children('.element:last-of-type');

        }
            elementExpand(prev_element);


    }
})
```

It's not the sleekest, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

Then use a regular selector, not `next()`.

```
$('.element').each(function() {
      alert($(this).text());
})
```

Comment: Not exactly what I'm trying to do. I clarified my question above.